# Copy with a list of files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a weird script that take a list of files and want to copy them to other folders.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

function_name=copy_verifier
envs=(one two)
files_to_copy=( index.js config/default.js )

for env in "${envs[@]}"
do
  env_function_name="${function_name}"_"$env"
  echo "$(tput setaf 3)  -> Copying ${env_function_name}$(tput sgr0)"
  mkdir -p "${env_function_name}/config"
  cp -rf ${files_to_copy[@]} ${env_function_name}/
done

echo -e "$(tput setaf 4)-> Done updating$(tput sgr0)"
```

The problem is file in `config/` folder are never copied. Do I need to iterate on each file to be able to copy them?

I'm on OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `rsync` instead.

`rysnc -r ${files_to_copy[@]} ${env_function_name}/`

Answer (score 0):

You are using variables incorrectly:

```
$function_name
```

Should be:

```
${function_name}
```

Otherwise it is equivalent to:

```
${function}_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The file in `config/` is actually copied into your `$env_function_name/`. If you need to copy `./config/default.js` into `$env_function_name/config/` you could try

```
cp -f --parents ${files_to_copy[@]} $env_function_name
```

Comment: Sadly I don't have function --parents option here :/

Comment: ok it's works with `rsync -R ${files_to_copy[@]} $env_function_name`. I let you change your answer so you can get karma. :)

Comment: No worries. `rsync` is fine. You could write it as separate answer, cheers.